# Problem installing Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server with .ebextensions on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install Microsoft `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, `gcc-c++` and `unixODBC-devel` using .ebextensions with the below config file. When I try to create the environment with `eb create` from the command line, the environment goes to a state where I got no choice but to kill the environment. I can't even see the logs. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

install_odbc.config file

```
commands:
    010_install_odbc:
        command: |
            # Enable epel
            sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel epel-source epel-debuginfo
            # Install Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
            # Also disable "annoying" priorities plugin while installing
            curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/8/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
            sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts
            sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install --disableplugin=priorities -y msodbcsql17
            # Insall gcc-c++ and unixODBC-devel
            # Also disable "annoying" priorities plugin while installing
            sudo yum install --disableplugin=priorities gcc-c++
            sudo yum install --disableplugin=priorities unixODBC-devel
        test: "! yum list installed unixODBC unixODBC-devel"
```

Comment: Try removing the commands one-by-one from the bottom up until you see some logs or a different error, or until it installs successfully with no errors. That will narrow down the scope and inform you of which installation command is causing you issues.

Comment: @LansanaCamara I will try that!